# Issues to Set Image as watermark in pdf using itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

I am trying to add image in PDF using itextsharp , but issues is image not set proper in background(watermark).

I want like this:

[image]

But the output is like this:

[image]

Here some code I am posting:

```
public class PdfWriterEvents : IPdfPageEvent
{
    string watermarkText = string.Empty;

    public PdfWriterEvents(string watermark)
    {
        watermarkText = watermark;
    }
    public void OnStartPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
    {
        float fontSize = 80;
        float xPosition = iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Width / 2;
        float yPosition = (iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Height - 140f) / 2;
        float angle = 45;
        try
        {
            PdfContentByte under = writer.DirectContentUnder;
            Image image = Image.GetInstance(watermarkText);
            image.SetAbsolutePosition(55f, 55f);                
            under.AddImage(image);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    public void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) { }
    public void OnParagraph(PdfWriter writer, Document document, float paragraphPosition) { }
    public void OnParagraphEnd(PdfWriter writer, Document document, float paragraphPosition) { }
    public void OnChapter(PdfWriter writer, Document document, float paragraphPosition, Paragraph title) { }
    public void OnChapterEnd(PdfWriter writer, Document document, float paragraphPosition) { }
    public void OnSection(PdfWriter writer, Document document, float paragraphPosition, int depth, Paragraph title) { }
    public void OnSectionEnd(PdfWriter writer, Document document, float paragraphPosition) { }
    public void OnGenericTag(PdfWriter writer, Document document, Rectangle rect, String text) { }
    public void OnOpenDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document) { }
    public void OnCloseDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document) { }
}
```

Calling code here :

```
writer.PageEvent = new PdfWriterEvents(LogoImage);
```

Comment: *"I want like this: ... But the output is like this: ..."* - Obviously, you **A** have to replace your image by an image with the colors you want (admittedly, you *can* change coloration using PDF methods but why don't you simply use an image which already is colored as desired?) and **B** have to scale the `Image image` to fit the space.

Comment: yes , i want image as background as watermark and I try by this code (which i got from internet) but output is like what in second (B) image so how to do that for all page as watermark @mkl and that first image(A) its html view (screenshot) second (B) image is pdf view(screenshot).

Comment: If in both screenshots the same image has been used as background, then surely in HTML some special attributes were set to remove the colors because iText does not invent them out of thin air.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's plenty of unnecessary lines in your code. For instance, you define `fontSize`, `xPosition`, `yPosition`, and `angle`, but you aren't doing anything with those variables. It's as if you copy/pasted some code from the internet, without understanding what that code is supposed to do. That's odd.

Suppose that you want to scale the image so that it fits the page size, then you have to get the width and the height of the page: `document.PageSize.Width` and `document.PageSize.Height`.

Then you have to make the decision whether or not you want the image to keep its aspect ratio. If not, you can use `img.ScaleAbsolute(width, height)`, but be aware that this can distort your image. If you want to avoid this distortion, you should use the `ScaleToFit()` method:

```
public void OnStartPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
{
    float width = document.PageSize.Width;
    float height = document.PageSize.Height;
    try
    {
        PdfContentByte under = writer.DirectContentUnder;
        Image image = Image.GetInstance(watermarkText);              
        image.ScaleToFit(width, height);
        image.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);  
        under.AddImage(image);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

In this sample, I used `0`, `0` as offset. I don't know how much margin you want (you'll have to adapt `width` and `height` if you want a margin), nor do I know if you want to center the image (that will require some primary school Math).

In any case, this answer solves your main problem: you forgot to scale the image.

Comment: first thank you @Bruno Lowagie , you are correct I just change some part in your code like **image.ScaleToFit(width, height);** to  **image.ScaleToFit(275f, 275f);** and  **image.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);** to **image.SetAbsolutePosition(150, 300);**  (make image in center of pdf)